# JavaCompiler not working in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, build, jar

I got a java program which uses a JavaCompiler to generate new class files.

I use jdk 1.6 within eclipse and this works fine.

But when I export this as jar file and wan't to compile some .java files it gives me a null error (because there is no compiler in the system used jre?).
is there a way to provide the compiler within the jar file?

```
File fRun = new File("someFile.java");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "-d", currentDir+"\\bin\\"} );
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compUnits =  fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(fRun);
Boolean compRes = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, compUnits).call();           

if(compRes == true){
    System.out.println("Compilation has succeeded");
    fileManager.close();
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Class<?> compiledClass = cl.loadClass(someFile);
    cRun = compiledClass;
}else{
    System.out.println("Compilation error");
    fileManager.close();
    throw new Exception("Compilation Error");
}
```

Comment: have u added a jre in eclipse?

Comment: what is the output of `java -version` .  Also can you type `javac` on the system where you are running and get a response?

Comment: java -version: java version "1.7.0_02" <br> Java<TM>SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13) <br> Java HotSpot<TM> Client VM (build 2.0-b10,mixed mode,sharing) @ frewper everything works fine in eclipse, just not anymore when I export as a runnable jar file

Comment: can the system find `javac` ?  The only thing I can think is you don't have a JDK on your system path (the one outside of eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you--> http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/05/using_java_comp.html Look for "...The standard technique for compiling Java source files in regular standalone application is to use the tools.jar that resides under jdk/lib ..."

Answer (score 1):

You should find where the implementation of JavaCompiler comes from (I'm guessing tools.jar from the JDK), and then you can include that in your classpath.  As the article linked by @Chuck in his answer shows, that jar is very large and might be unacceptable to deploy.  If so, you maay want to consider the other options described in that article.